# How do you move multiple files in git?

Tags: git

I try:

`git mv a.py b.py src/`

and get

`fatal: multiple sources for the same target, source=b.py, destination=src/b.py`

Using the -n flag, like so `git mv -n a.py b.py src/`
gives me:

```
Checking rename of 'a.py' to 'src/b.py'
Checking rename of 'b.py' to 'src/b.py'
fatal: multiple sources for the same target, source=b.py, destination=src/b.py
```

Am I doing something really stupid? I'm using git version 1.6.6.1

Comment: I should probably say that I'm running the macports git (version 1.6.6.1) on a mac.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This has been fixed in the current master branch of git, it's in v1.7.0-rc0 but not in a release build yet.

http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=af82559b435aa2a18f38a4f47a93729c8dc543d3

In the mean time the simplest thing to do is to either `git mv` the files individually or to just use `mv` and then update the index manually, e.g. with `git add -A` if you have appropriate `.gitignore` patterns.

Comment: I had missed -A as a switch to Add, very useful :)

Comment: git add ./ Also works!  But even better is that at least in git version 1.9 and later, the ability to move multiple files at once works totally fine.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? [This](https://superuser.com/a/1591487/1225721) otoh works for me

Answer (score 32):

I use bash loop:

```
for FILE in src/*.h; do git mv $FILE include/; done
```

Comment: Can this be modified to rename for example all `a_1_b.ext` --> `a_2_b.ext`?

Answer (score 29):

In Windows (PowerShell):

```
foreach ($file in get-childitem *.py) { git mv $file.name ./src }
```

Comment: Thank you, you can use the -n switch in order to test if it would work (so-called dry-run). Useful. Does anyone know how to do this from SourceTree? I cannot find the command there.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like magic as it ought to!! :)

Answer (score 15):

As long as there aren’t any other changes in the working directory, the simplest way is just to move them yourself and then use `git add -A`. Behold:

```
$ ls
a.py b.py
$ mkdir src
$ mv *.py src
$ git status
# Changed but not updated:
#       deleted:    a.py
#       deleted:    b.py
# Untracked files:
#       src/
$ git add -A
$ git status
# Changes to be committed:
#       renamed:    a.py -> src/a.py
#       renamed:    b.py -> src/b.py
```

Comment: I can't say it's good, but I've never used `git rm` - just move the files myself and add tell `git` to add them later. The good thing is, `git` does recognize them as the same files.

Comment: Pretty sure that's going to lose file history

Answer (score 11):

Works for me:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.6.4.1
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/wich/foo
$ touch a b c d
$ git add a b c d
$ git commit -m "foobar"
[master (root-commit) 11051bd] foo
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b
 create mode 100644 c
 create mode 100644 d
$ mkdir bar
$ git mv a b c d bar
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       renamed:    a -> bar/a
#       renamed:    b -> bar/b
#       renamed:    c -> bar/c
#       renamed:    d -> bar/d
#
```

Comment: I'll try with a newer version

Comment: Works for me in git version 1.7.9. You could also use wildcards `git mv [abcd] bar/` (although I think the shell expands them, so git sees it the same as wich's solution.